# JavaScript Dynamic Scoring Matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix

I need a way to implement a dynamic scoring matrix in JavaScript. I have created a fiddle here:

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/w4avu3er/78/)

The first two questions about which school you went to show/hide other questions.

So there are 4 possible cases based on the answers to the first two questions:

Answer only the questions that are always displayed
Answer the questions that are always displayed plus High School Questions
Answer the questions that are always displayed plus Elementary School Questions
Answer the questions that are always displayed plus Elementary & High School Questions

To dynamically loop over the questions that need to be answered I need to construct an array of visible questions (not including the questions about which school you went to).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // INITALISE OPTIONAL QUESTION GROUPS HIDDEN
  $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').hide();
  $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').hide();


  // SHOW/HIDE HIGH SCHOOL QUESTIONS
  $(document).on('change', '.selectpicker.highschool', function() {
console.log('high school changed');
if ($('.selectpicker.highschool').val() == 1) {
  $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').show();
}
if ($('.selectpicker.highschool').val() == 0) {
  $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').hide();
}
});

  // SHOW/HIDE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL QUESTIONS
  $(document).on('change', '.selectpicker.elementaryschool', function() {
    if ($('.selectpicker.elementaryschool').val() == 1) {
      $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').show();
    }
if ($('.selectpicker.elementaryschool').val() == 0) {
  $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').hide();
}

var questionsVisible = [];
$(document).on('change', '.selectpicker.schoolgroup', function() {
  // I WANT TO SCORE ONLY THE VISIBLE QUESTIONS - HOW TO CONSTRUCT AN ARRAY TO DO THIS?
  $('.selectpicker.highschoolquestion:visible').each(function() {
    questionsVisible.push(this);
    console.log('pause');
    });
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: There are features in JS, and also in jQuery, that use string as a value, which you can use as data ...

Comment: How does that help? I need to construct an array of the questions to be scored based on whether or not the question is visible?

Comment: The comment is as clear as your question, you never said what is wrong with your code, "_I am stuck_" is not very descriptive problem description. Also, it looks like you're getting the array, only that you throw it away immediately after created it ..?

Comment: I told you exactly which bit I am stuck on and its commented in the code too. Make sure you quote in full context.

Comment: "I am stuck" and "_HOW TO CONSTRUCT AN ARRAY_" describe your problem, not what is going wrong with the program ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is working solution:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/k3azfm7u/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // INITALISE OPTIONAL QUESTION GROUPS HIDDEN
  $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').hide();
  $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').hide();


  // SHOW/HIDE HIGH SCHOOL QUESTIONS
  $(document).on('change', '.selectpicker.highschool', function() {
    console.log('high school changed');
    if ($('.selectpicker.highschool').val() == 1) {
      $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').show();
    }
    if ($('.selectpicker.highschool').val() == 0) {
      $('.form-group.highschoolquestions').hide();
    }
  });

  // SHOW/HIDE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL QUESTIONS
  $(document).on('change', '.selectpicker.elementaryschool', function() {
    if ($('.selectpicker.elementaryschool').val() == 1) {
      $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').show();
    }
    if ($('.selectpicker.elementaryschool').val() == 0) {
      $('.form-group.elementaryschoolquestions').hide();
    }

  });
      $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
      // I WANT TO SCORE ONLY THE VISIBLE QUESTIONS - HOW TO CONSTRUCT AN ARRAY TO DO THIS?
      var total = 0;
      $('.score-select select:visible').each(function() {
       var val = parseInt($(this).val())
        total += val > 0 ? val :0;
        console.log('pause');
      });
      $('#todayscore').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to mark the score as "Uncomplete" until all visible questions are answered?

Comment: You need to decide this what the criteria, "No" is also answer.

Comment: Both No and Yes are valid answers. Thanks